# Проверить наличие скролла на JS

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить, есть ли на странице скролл или нет?

Comment: проверить разность `document.body.clientHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight`

Comment: @Spectre, если его нет, то значение отрицательное, верно?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/681729

Answer (score 6, accepted):

если `document.scrollHeight` равен `document.offsetHeight` то скрола нет

Comment: Это не так, в хроме если ввести на этой странице `document.documentElement.scrollHeight == document.documentElement.offsetHeight`, например, то будет тру, что означает по-твоему, что скролла нет. А он есть.

Comment: @VostokSisters, и оба `undefined`. Вместо `document` должен быть dom-элемент, который мы реально проверяем на наличие скролла. В случае всей страницы это не работает (точнее, может работать или не работать в зависимости от css, но по умолчанию не работает) - она несколько особенная, но для обычных элементов подойдёт. Например, на [скролящемся блоке кода в вопросе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621344/178988) срабатывает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, из другого моего тебе комментария:  я вот сделал полностью работающую [штуку](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/LxeXYj?editors=0010), которая говорит, есть ли скролл у элемента или у боди, или нет (учитываются даже заданные overflow: scroll).

Comment: @Qwertiy, а насчет того, что это каркас для конкретного элемента в ответе не сказано. Вопрос звучит как? Наличие скролла на странице. На странице. Именно. А не на элементе. Я считаю, это не ответ на вопрос совершенно.

Answer (score 3):

просто и кроссбрузерно

```
if(-[1,]){
    if (document.body.offsetHeight > window.innerHeight) {
        alert("Скролл есть");
    } else {
        alert("Скролла нет");
    }

} else {
    if (document.body.offsetHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        alert("Скролл есть");
    else {
        alert("Скролла нет");
    }
}
```

Comment: фу, браузердетект на баге...

Comment: @eicto, и что же в этом плохого?

Comment: @Qwertiy, подскажите, пожалуйста, а что такое браузердетект? Гугл чес-слово не находит. И что означает `-[1,]` запись в первом условии в ответе?

Comment: @VostokSisters, browser detection - определение браузера.

Comment: @Qwertiy, и каким образом тут детектится браузер?

Comment: @VostokSisters, стандарт js говорит, что `[1,]` - это массив из одного элемента `1` - так же как `[1]`. Но в IE был косяк и получалось `[1, undefined]`. Хватило бы проверить длину, но человек пошёл другим путём - поставил унарный минус. В этом случае массив кастится в строку, а затем в число, к которому и применяется унарный минус. Правильный массив превращается в строку `"1"`, затем число `1` и в итоге получается `-1` - истинное значение. А вот неправильный - в строку `"1,"`, которая не является валидным числом (запятая - это не точка), получается `NaN` и в итоге тоже `NaN` - ложное значение.

Comment: @Qwertiy, о-о-о-о, эти костыли (: Я недавно в вебе, так что не знаю даже про самые известные хаки для IE. Так что это не могло быть мне понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно такую штуку проверить на `jQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#object').scroll(function(){
        alert('Был осуществлен Scroll');
    });
});
```

Comment: @lamS, а если его нет? То как?

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_scroll(a) {
  var d = document,
      b = d.body,
      e = d.documentElement,
      c = "client" + a;
      a = "scroll" + a;
  return /CSS/.test(d.compatMode)? (e[c]< e[a]) : (b[c]< b[a])
};
```

**Использование:**

- `get_scroll('Width')` – есть ли горизонтальный скролл
- `get_scroll('Height')` – есть ли вертикальный скролл

Answer (score 1):

```js
const block = document.getElementById('block'); // целевой блок
const isVerticalScroll= block.scrollHeight > block.clientHeight; // вертикальный скролл
const isHorizontalScroll= block.scrollWidth > block.clientWidth; // горизонтальный скролл
console.log({isVerticalScroll, isHorizontalScroll})
```

```html
<div id="block" style="width: 150px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; background: gray;">
  <div style="height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid"></div>
  <div style="height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid"></div>
  <div style="height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid"></div>
  <div style="height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid"></div>
  <div style="height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid"></div>
  <div style="height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid"></div>
  <div style="height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid"></div>
  <div style="height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid"></div>
  <div style="height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null

Comment: Прикрутил визуализацию расчёта

Answer (score 0):

У меня сработало так

```js
if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
  // there is scroll
}
```

Answer (score 0):

для меня сработало вот такое сравнение:

```
(document.body.scrollHeight !== window.innerHeight)
```

а эти вещи `document.scrollHeight  document.offsetHeight`
всегда равны у меня...