# Определить в Jquery (Обработчик событии) когда создается scrolling прокрутка

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Есть обработчик `onscroll`. Событие `onscroll` происходит, когда элемент прокручивается. Но мне нужно определить возникновение самого ползунка, а не процесс прокручивание. 
То есть нужно обработчик событии, который сработает, как только на документе появиться `scroll-bar`.

Comment: То есть нужно узнать существует ли в данный момент на странице Scroll-bar?

Comment: Если так, то вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/195849/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверить наличие скролла на JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/195849/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-js)

Comment: @Cheg там, к сожалению, нет правильного ответа...

Comment: Можно и так описать проблему. Надо такой  обработчик событий, который дает нам знать, когда в документе появляется скролл-бар.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, проверить, есть ли полоса прокрутки или нет, легко. Сложно выполнить код сразу, как только она появится.

Для запуска функции, когда появляется полоса, я использовал JQuery плагин отслежки изменения размера блока и повесил его на сенсор внутри нужного элемента.

```js
(function () {
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
        return null;
    }
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function (fn) {
            return window.setTimeout(fn, 20);
        };

    $.fn.onResize = function (callback) {
        var $target = $(this);

        function EventQueue() {
            var q = [];
            this.add = function (ev) {
                q.push(ev);
            };

            var i, j;
            this.call = function () {
                for (i = 0, j = q.length; i < j; i++) {
                    q[i].call();
                }
            };

            this.remove = function (ev) {
                var newQueue = [];
                for (i = 0, j = q.length; i < j; i++) {
                    if (q[i] !== ev) newQueue.push(q[i]);
                }
                q = newQueue;
            }

            this.length = function () {
                return q.length;
            }
        }

        function attachResizeEvent($target, resized) {
            if (!$target) return;
            if ($target.resizedAttached) {
                $target.resizedAttached.add(resized);
                return;
            }

            $target.resizedAttached = new EventQueue();
            $target.resizedAttached.add(resized);

            $target.resizeElement = document.createElement('div');
            $target.resizeElement.className = 'resize-sensor';
            var style = 'position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;';
            var styleChild = 'position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transition: 0s;';

            $target.resizeElement.style.cssText = style;
            $target.resizeElement.innerHTML = '<div class="resize-sensor-expand" style="' + style + '"><div style="' + styleChild + '"></div></div><div class="resize-sensor-shrink" style="' + style + '"><div style="' + styleChild + ' width: 200%; height: 200%"></div></div>';
            $target.appendChild($target.resizeElement);

            if ($target.resizeElement.offsetParent !== $target) {
                $target.style.position = 'relative';
            }

            var el__expand = $target.resizeElement.childNodes[0];
            var el__expandChild = el__expand.childNodes[0];
            var el__shrink = $target.resizeElement.childNodes[1];
            var dirty, rafId, int__newWidth, int__newHeight;
            var int__lastWidth = $target.offsetWidth;
            var int__lastHeight = $target.offsetHeight;

            var reset = function () {
                el__expandChild.style.width = '100000px';
                el__expandChild.style.height = '100000px';

                el__expand.scrollLeft = 100000;
                el__expand.scrollTop = 100000;

                el__shrink.scrollLeft = 100000;
                el__shrink.scrollTop = 100000;
            };

            reset();

            var onResized = function () {
                rafId = 0;

                if (!dirty) return;

                int__lastWidth = int__newWidth;
                int__lastHeight = int__newHeight;

                if ($target.resizedAttached) {
                    $target.resizedAttached.call();
                }
            };

            var onScroll = function () {
                int__newWidth = $target.offsetWidth;
                int__newHeight = $target.offsetHeight;
                dirty = int__newWidth != int__lastWidth || int__newHeight != int__lastHeight;

                if (dirty && !rafId) {
                    rafId = requestAnimationFrame(onResized);
                }

                reset();
            };

            var addEvent = function (el, name, cb) {
                if (el.attachEvent) {
                    el.attachEvent('on' + name, cb);
                } else {
                    el.addEventListener(name, cb);
                }
            };

            addEvent(el__expand, 'scroll', onScroll);
            addEvent(el__shrink, 'scroll', onScroll);
        }

        $target.each(function () {
            attachResizeEvent(this, callback);
        });

        this.detach = function (ev) {
            $.fn.onResize.detach($target, ev);
        };
    };

    $.fn.onResize.detach = function ($target, ev) {
        $target.each(function () {
            if (!this) return
            if (this.resizedAttached && typeof ev == "function") {
                this.resizedAttached.remove(ev);
                if (this.resizedAttached.length()) return;
            }
            if (this.resizeElement) {
                if (this.contains(this.resizeElement)) {
                    this.removeChild(this.resizeElement);
                }
                delete this.resizeElement;
                delete this.resizedAttached;
            }
        });
    };
})();

var $wrap = $('.wrap'),
    $wrap_sensor = $('.wrap_sensor');

$wrap_sensor.onResize(function() {
  var $wrap = $('.wrap');

  if($wrap.get(0).clientHeight !== $wrap.get(0).scrollHeight) console.log('Появилась полоса');
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.wrap_body {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 800px;
}
input:checked ~ .wrap > .wrap_body {
  display: block;
}

.wrap_sensor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Добавить полосу: <input type="checkbox">

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="wrap_sensor"></div>
  <div class="wrap_body"></div>
</div>
```